# Irreducible representation and $M(n, \mathbb{C})$

Tags: representation-theory

If $\rho:G\to GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ is irreducible. I wonder how to apply Shur’s Lemma to see that:

The elements of $\rho(G)$ linearly span the space of $n\times n$ matrices, $M(n,\mathbb{C})$.

Conversely, if $\rho$ is not irreducible, then the elements of $\rho(G)$ do not span $M(n,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: I think this requires slightly more than Schur's lemma. It follows from the double centralizer theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_centralizer_theorem

Comment: There is a proof of this near the beginning of Chapter 2 of Etingof’s “Introduction to Representation Theory”. The proof works for any finite-dimensional (semisimple?) algebra over an algebraically closed field.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan can you give more explanations? Your theorem is for ring while I am considering a group.

Comment: @Joppy can you point out where? I didn’t see that proof. Only only see the center of G is mapped to a scalar

Comment: You apply the double centralizer theorem to the (image of the) group algebra $\mathbb{C}[G]$. Saying that the elements of $\rho(G)$ span is equivalent to saying that the induced map $\mathbb{C}[G] \to M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is surjective.

Comment: I think Etingof calls it the “density theorem”.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I can see for the induced map $\phi:\mathbb{C}[G]\to M_n(\mathbb{C})$, $\phi(C(\mathbb{C}[G]))=C(M_n(\mathbb{C}))$, but I don't see why $\phi(C(C(\mathbb{C}[G])))=C(C(M_n(\mathbb{C})))$

Comment: @Joppy then why if $\rho$ is not irreducible, then the elements of $\rho(G)$ do not span $M(n,\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: If the representation splits as $V = X \oplus Y$ for nonzero $X$ and $Y$, then there is a basis of $V$ where all of the corresponding matrices of the group actions are block-diagonal.